# Finding the kernel between two quotient modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, modules, complex-geometry

The quesition arises from Demailly's *Complex Analytic and Differential Geometry,* Chapter 4, 10. page 224, Lemma 10.3.

He first defined the filtration of a $R$-module and the associated graded module.
[image]

Then he stated the Lemma 10.3 which is useful for defining the complex $E_r^{\bullet}=\bigoplus_{p\in\mathbb Z}E^p_r$.[image]

What confuses me is the right part in my second image. How can we get the kernel between these two quotient modules?

More general, assume we have two quotient $R$-modules ($R$ is a commutative ring) $H_1=A/B$, $H_2=C/D$, and a morphism $\varphi$ between them. Then how to determine the kernel?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your "more general" question is missing some assumptions: you probably want this map between $H_1$ and $H_2$ to be induced by some other map you already know, otherwise if you let $B=D=0$, then you're just asking "what's the kernel of $A\to C$", where the best answer one can give is $\ker A\to C$, and that's boring.